# passing an arraylist from one intent to another

Tags: android, arraylist

am trying to pass an arrylist from one intent to another.
My code is as follows:

```
intent.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
intent.putExtra("nearby", nearbylist);
```

and at the new intent i do this:

```
nearPlaces = (PlacesList) extras.getSerializable("near_places");
nearbylist = (ArrayList<FsqVenue>)extras.getArrayList("nearby");
```

the code for the firat is correct but for the second it shows me errors where fsqVenue is a class

please help me

Comment: Read up on Parcelables: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make sure FsqVenue class implements  `Serializable` interface then use this code for getting ArrayList in other Activity :

```
nearbylist = (ArrayList<FsqVenue>)extras.getSerializable("nearby");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
near_places = i.getStringArrayListExtra("nearPlaces");
```

that's perfect work please try and give replay.

Answer (score 0):

Princewill, here is your answer :- [I want to let user add multiple items by action sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189354/i-want-to-let-user-add-multiple-items-by-action-sequence), i have done this and looking for to make it more advanced.....JUST OPEN LINK AND VIEW code for Catalogue and SingleMenuItem Activity and done.