# I want to let user add multiple items by action sequence

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am making an app in which I am fetching data using JSON into ListView, and allowing user to view selected item in another form, in singleMenuItem form.

I have placed a button namely - Add to Cart. Whenever users will click on the Add to Cart button, the selected item needs to show in the View Cart form. The same process will be repeated for each item which is added to the cart.

I just want to show each Item's Title and Cost, for those I am fetching into the `SingleMenuItem` form using Intent from `ListView` Form  and now I want to show in View Cart Form like:- add multiple items by action sequence, the problem is  I don't know how to update View Cart form every time whenever user click on Add to Cart Button.

Catalogue(List View Activity) Code:-

```
public class Catalogue  extends Activity{

    static String URL = "http:/--------/and/menu.json";
    static String KEY_CATEGORY = "item";    
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);            
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, itemsList);        
list.setAdapter(adapter);


Intent in = getIntent();

KEY_CATEGORY = in.getStringExtra("category");
    
                           try{

                 JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(KEY_CATEGORY);
                 
                    for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){                        

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                     
                        
                        map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE));
                        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, jsonObject.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION));
                        map.put(KEY_COST, jsonObject.getString(KEY_COST));
                        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, jsonObject.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL));
                    
                    
                    itemsList.add(map);
                    

                        
                  } 
                    return itemsList;
            }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }
                           
                return null;
              
                }
                 
              
          @Override
          
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);            
                adapter=new LazyAdapter(Catalogue.this, itemsList);        
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                          HashMap<String, String> map = itemsList.get(position);
                        
                        Intent in = new Intent(Catalogue.this, SingleMenuItem.class);
                        in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, map.get(KEY_DESCRIPTION));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));
                        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, map.get(KEY_COST));
                        startActivity(in);
                    }

        
                });     
                
               ImageButton viewShoppingCart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonViewCart);
               viewShoppingCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent in = new Intent
                               (Catalogue.this, FinalOrder.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        
                    }
                });

                

          } }}
```

---

SingleMenuItem Activity Code

```
   public class SingleMenuItem extends Activity{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";
private EditText edit_qty_code;
private TextView txt_total;
private TextView text_cost_code;
private double itemamount = 0;
private double itemquantity = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    final String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);
    
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    
    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);
    TextView txtcost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    TextView txtheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    
    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtheader.setText(title);
    txtcost.setText(cost);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);
    
  
 
    ImageButton addToCartButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_add);
    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {                               
        Intent in = new Intent
               (SingleMenuItem.this, FinalOrder.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE)); 
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_COST));
            startActivity(in);
        
            
            // Close the activity
                finish();
            }
        });    
}}
```

---

ViewCart Activity Code:-

```
public class FinalOrder extends Activity
{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view);     


Intent in = getIntent();

String title1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
String cost1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

TextView txttitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
TextView txtcost1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_cost);

txttitle1.setText(title1);
txtcost1.setText(cost1);    

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the View Cart to update, you need to store the data centrally.  Best to use an SQLite database.  Then you can update this database when a user adds to the cart, then when viewing the cart, you can read from the database.

Comment: here i am using json data, any other way

Comment: Maybe not SQLite, but you need to save the data somewhere.  The FinalOrder activity can't be guaranteed to exist while your are in your List Activity, therefore you can't just update the values on it.

Comment: I was going to delete my answer, even though you haven't said why my ideas are "wrong" (this is how a shopping cart normally works), but I'll leave it here to see how helpful your comments are to anyone else thinking of answering.

Comment: I want to add multiple products under the same form how can I add it can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?