# How to using service and methods of Activity right?

Tags: android, service, android-intent, android-activity

I want post action from child view to activity current throught server or methods of activity, how to using this methods ? Please help me!
Thanks everyone.

Comment: why not callbacks like it's done in androids views?

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful for you,:- view link and read all three activity code:- [I want to let user add multiple items by action sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189354/i-want-to-let-user-add-multiple-items-by-action-sequence)

Comment: My application is the same as your application, but i have only 1 activity, in this activity, i have a list item and a cartView, i want when select option in list item , cartview is updated immediately. >"<

I don't know how to update cartview every time when I select the option in the list item

Comment: Nguyen Nhai Tai, which parser u are using is it Json or XML first of all tell this or making static one

Comment: i using JSON and parse it by a method i write, important is that I didn't catch the change of view child of listview

Comment: @Nguyen i want to see your code or send me your code as zip then i will make it for you, if possible ???

Comment: i have seen you have send me only java classes code, send complete because it will take huge time to make manifest and their permissions, res folder, so send complete means:- src, res, androidmanifest, then i will just run, and finally i will add cartview functionality that's it and then will give you back with cartview activity code ok

Comment: Thank you, however my app quite large and are commercialized shouldn't show all , you can give me an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: i just wanted that for you and just for you, i have made many more, anyways, no problem, i can send you complete source code, just write your email id which is not commercial

Comment: Thanks so much, my email: nguyennhattai07@gmail.com

Comment: No problem, i will make do some changes in my shopping cart app and will give as shopping cart tutorial, you can use as you like, because i will give particular that module which exactly you need as same way i was asking to send me not whole ok buddy....

Comment: i have sent you check you mail

Comment: I got the email, thank you for your help, but my app was forced to lie on one activity and the only event that I get from view of listview item, how to know that I just edit on EditText of listview item?